# Batch Application on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, batch-processing, scheduling

I have a batch application which need to be ported to Bluemix. Are there any scheduler available on bluemix where i can schedule my batch application or only way is to host it as web application and trigger the url via an external scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Atul you can try using the workload scheduler for your task.

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/workload-scheduler/